# Getting right information from the list

Tags: python

I have following part of list obtained from the csv file (csv downloaded from Shopify).

```
['#1762', 'lukg@ttt.com.au', 'paid', '2020-08-20 09:08:13 +1000', 'fulfilled',
 '2020-08-20 09:27:27 +1000', 'yes', 'AUD', '273.90', '0.00', '24.90', '273.90',
 '""', '0.00', 'Free shipping to your address', '2020-08-20 08:36:29 +1000',
 '1', 'Standard Hand Sanitiser Station - Free-Standing - Black', '273.90',
 '328.90', 'EC-HSS-FS-S-A-B', 'true', 'true', 'fulfilled', 'Luke Smith',
 '211 Riond Rd', '211 Riond Rd', '""', '""', 'Riond', "'5033", 'SA', 'AU',
 '0439 082 558', 'Luke Smith', '211 Riond Rd', '211 Riond Rd', '""', '""',
 'Riond', "'5033", 'SA', 'AU', '043*******58', '""', '""', '',
 'Shopify Payments', 'c1462*******524.1', '0.00', 'Expo Lite', '0.00', '', '',
 '', '264*******220', '""', 'Low', 'web', '0.00', 'GST 10%', '24.90', '', '',
 '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Is there efficient way to get out customer name, email and product purchased?

The issue is that there are number of similar lists in .csv file, but if I use something like this

```
email = list[1]
name = list[24]
product = list[17]
```

not the same information obtained from the list and sometimes its item before or after. When I check csv file, the information is all structured correctly and there is no read missing the index.

I'm sorry if question is silly, I cannot wrap my head around this. :(

Comment: If they're all in columns, they should be in the same location every time.

Comment: How are you reading the csv? Are you using the csv module or did you write your own code?

Comment: Could also be that some of the strings have commas. If possible it would be better to save as a pipe separated file

Comment: Are you using the Export orders function in Shopify for this? I can update the example to reflect that if you need, or you can just add in the headers you need.

Comment: I opened file with open("orders.csv", "r") as file: read = file.readlines()... then strip and split on "," and appended to an empty list; so I got nested lists for each order.

Comment: Use the csv module. This will properly handle the case when you have commas in your data. This would explain why you are getting the required fields appearing at different indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how to do this using the [Shopify product_template.csv](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/import-export/using-csv#get-a-sample-csv-file) as an example. This is using DictReader and explicit delimiters+quotechar.

```py
import csv

with open('product_template.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Handle'], row['Vendor'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the items are always in the same index position in the list, a *very* good way would be to use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a function that retrieved all the items at once. It's efficient in the sense that the setup only has to be done once, and it's implemented in a highly-optimized built-in module. Here's what I mean:

```
from operator import itemgetter


data = ['#1762', 'lukg@ttt.com.au', 'paid', '2020-08-20 09:08:13 +1000', 'fulfilled',
 '2020-08-20 09:27:27 +1000', 'yes', 'AUD', '273.90', '0.00', '24.90', '273.90',
 '""', '0.00', 'Free shipping to your address', '2020-08-20 08:36:29 +1000',
 '1', 'Standard Hand Sanitiser Station - Free-Standing - Black', '273.90',
 '328.90', 'EC-HSS-FS-S-A-B', 'true', 'true', 'fulfilled', 'Luke Smith',
 '211 Riond Rd', '211 Riond Rd', '""', '""', 'Riond', "'5033", 'SA', 'AU',
 '0439 082 558', 'Luke Smith', '211 Riond Rd', '211 Riond Rd', '""', '""',
 'Riond', "'5033", 'SA', 'AU', '043*******58', '""', '""', '',
 'Shopify Payments', 'c1462*******524.1', '0.00', 'Expo Lite', '0.00', '', '',
 '', '264*******220', '""', 'Low', 'web', '0.00', 'GST 10%', '24.90', '', '',
 '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

data_getter = itemgetter(1, 24, 17)       # Create function.
email, name, product = data_getter(data)  # Use it.
print(email, name, product, sep=',')      # Display results.
```

Output:

```
lukg@ttt.com.au,Luke Smith,Standard Hand Sanitiser Station - Free-Standing - Black
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about such way.